# Missing records from solr index?

Tags: solr, solrnet, solr4

Is there anyway to find the missing records from solr index.

I am running crawling against a SQL DB. My primaryKey is "id".

There are a few records missing in index. Is there any specific way to find those all??

Is it going to make any difference between a long value and string primary key, if we are using range query??

Thanks in advance....!!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that those records went "missing" during indexation, you can write them down in a file during indexation, because you will know more or less which records will not make it through.

If you are talking about comparing the database with Solr the only way is to crawl all the database and search for the record in Solr.
You can do it with a range query on group of ids if your ids are numeric for example and then if the result does not match you can narrow down the search.

they easiest way though is to just compare the ids one by one but it's also the slowest way. It depends on your database.

Primary keys in Solr are string only, but nobody say you can't have a numeric unique key alongside.